# SecondaryAuthenticationFactorRegistration API giving access denied exception in appx which is built using makeappx.exe tool

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, appx, appxmanifest, makeappx

I  am able to register companion device(mobile phone) with CDF framework in Win32 application.I am not getting any exception in this case.Then i have used MakeAppx tool to convert win32 application into appx. When i tried to register companion device with CDF framework using

```
      SecondaryAuthenticationFactorRegistrationResult registrationResult = await SecondaryAuthenticationFactorRegistration.RequestStartRegisteringDeviceAsync(deviceModelNumber,
                    capabilities,
                    deviceFriendlyName,
                    deviceModelNumber,
                    deviceKey,
                    authKey);
```

through appx, getting exception:
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I am referring the pure UWP sample for CDF framework from below link.

https://github.com/Microsoft/companion-device-framework

Also i have taken care of adding below capability to appxmanifest.xml while creating appx.

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="secondaryAuthenticationFactor" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  </Capabilities>
```

I am in trouble as appx created using makeappx tool throwing access denied exception where as win32 and sample pure UWP  application working fine.
Looking for the solution.

Comment: Could you show the target version of converted UWP app?

Comment: Nico,I knew while creating UWP app,we can set target version.But this is not pure UWP. I have converted Desktop application into appx using makeappx tool.Can you please guide me on setting or finding target version for an application which is going to be converted into appx using makeappx tool.Yes but i can tell the desktop application which has been converted to appx here  targets .Net Framework 4.5.2